# how to get the value of td of tablein javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
row.each(function (i, el) {

    var CustTd = $(el).find('td')[4];
    if (CustTd != undefined) {
        var CustTdvalue = CustTd.attr('value');
        if (CustTdvalue == filterValue)
        {
            $(el).show();
       }

    }

})
```

Hi this is my code related to the javascript and jquery  iam getting the td but i want to find out the value of value attribute of td

Comment: Please post your html

Comment: share your `html` code also!!

Comment: `$(el).find('td')[4]` would return a DOM element not a jQuery object.

Comment: Hi i am getting  <td value="6894">Abertis Infraestructuras <input type="hidden" id="hdnGroupName" value="6894"></td> html from CustTd and i want value="6894" which i want to compare with filter value

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(CustTd).attr('value')` instead of `CustTd.attr('value')` assuming that `value` attribute exist in `td`.

Answer (score 0):

```
row.each(function (i, el) {

                                  +--- This access returns a native
                                  |    DOM element rather than a 
                                  |    jQuery object.
                                  v
    var CustTd = $(el).find('td')[4];
    if (CustTd != undefined) {
        var CustTdvalue = CustTd.attr('value');
                                 ^
                                 |
                                 +----- This function doesn't exist
                                        for native DOM elements, you need
                                        either to wrap it with jQuery 
                                        function $ or use the function
                                        getAttribute('value').

        if (CustTdvalue == filterValue) {
            $(el).show();
       }

    }
});
```

A recommendation is to use the jQuery built-in function `$.data()`:

```
row.each(function (i, el) {

    var CustTd = $(el).find('td')[4];
    if (CustTd != undefined) {
        var CustTdvalue = $CustTd).data('value'); <--- Here .data() returns the current value (data-value)
        if (CustTdvalue == filterValue){
            $(el).show();
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<td data-value="6894">
```

## Resources

- [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)
- [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)
- [How do I pull a native DOM element from a jQuery object?](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)